# StackOverflowError in simple program

Tags: java

Dears, I want to implement this behavior:

"Trespassers will be shot, survivors will be shot again"

But I get this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.equals(String.java:975)
    at test.Person.isDead(Person.java:14)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:7)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
    at test.Shooter.shoot(Shooter.java:8)
```

The 'Property' class:

```
package test;

public class Property {

    private Shooter shooter = new Shooter();

    public void punish(Person tresspasser) {

        shooter.shoot(tresspasser);
    }
}
```

The Shooter class:

```
package test;

public class Shooter {

    public void shoot(Person person) {

        if(!person.isDead()){
            shoot(person);
        }
    }
}
```

The 'Person' class:

```
package test;

public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public void tresspass(Property property) {

        property.punish(this);
    }

    public boolean isDead(){

        return !name.equals("Chuck Norris");
    }
}
```

And finally, the Main class:

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Person person = new Person("Chuck Norris");

        Property myProperty = new Property();

        person.tresspass(myProperty);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I use eclipse and the problem occurs in Java 6, 7 and 8...

S.

Comment: s/Chuck Norris/Jon Skeet/

Comment: This is where stepping through your code in your debugger would help you see why it recurses forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in your Person Constructor. Add the clause

```
if(name.equals("Chuck Norris")){
    throw new ChuckNorrisException("Chuck Norris saw through your ploy to consider him a person");
}
```

and then you'll be fine.

Comment: I was always told to not throw a ChuckNorrisException otherwise the ChuckNorrisException would throw me...

Answer (score 10):

`return !name.equals("Chuck Norris");` always returns false if the person's name is "Chuck Norris" and therefore you loop infinitely.

You likely have limited ammo so you should consider some kind of ammunition functionality.

Comment: This person is immortal. Even you have unlimited ammo, you will spend your whole life shooting him, generation by generation.

Answer (score 3):

In the following snippet you loop on `shoot` while the person is alive. Since Chuck Norris can not die, you end up shooting infinitely on him and he ends up killing your program with a `StackOverflowError`:

```
public void shoot(Person person) {

    if(!person.isDead()){
        shoot(person);
    }
}
```

You can set a maximum number of ammunition or add a `firstShot` argument to allow only 2 shots. For example:

```
public void shoot(Person person) {
    shoot(person, true);
}

private void shoot(Person person, boolean firstShot) {
    if(firstShot && !person.isDead()) {
        shoot(person, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: but won't he be angry then?

Comment: If you shoot him only 2 times, I think he may not even notice it. So you should be safe.